# Why isn't xcode recognising "PFObject" in viewcontroller?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, parse-platform, pfobject

Ive been trying to get my app working with parse and i cannot get the test to work. I think it might be due to viewcontroller.m not recognising "PFObject". I need to add this into the view controller as the instructions say on parse.com but i cannot get it to work.

Has anyone had this problem or have any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post some code and any errors you are getting. The question is not clear enough without it.

Comment: Given the amount of information I have at this point, I think a likely candidate here is the work of supernatural forces.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you done `#import <Parse/Parse.h>` at the top of your view controller.m?

Comment: yes i did that. been trying to figure this out for a couple of days now!